# Marginal theorem in frequency-resolved optical gating (FROG)

Tags: laser, fourier-transform, correlation-functions, non-linear-optics

In ultrashort laser physics, [frequency-resolved optical gating (FROG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-resolved_optical_gating) has been a standard method since a few decades to measure the temporal profile of an unknown pulse's electric field $E(t)$ via a spectrally resolved nonlinear autocorrelation. The simplest and most popular FROG is second-harmonic FROG where the two delayed replica of the laser pulse are focused non-collinearly into a nonlinear crystal and create second-harmonic radiation when they overlap in time. By scanning the delay $\tau$ and recording the intensity spectrum (in $\omega$) of the second-harmonic radiation, the FROG spectrogram $I_\text{FROG}(\omega,\tau)$ is obtained:

$$I_\text{FROG}(\omega,\tau) = \left| \int_{-\infty}^\infty E(t)E(t-\tau) e^{-i \omega t} \,dt \right|^2$$

The integral is a Fourier transform in $t$ (to obtain the spectrum) and the transformed autocorrelation signal $E(t)E(t-\tau)$ can be expressed as another Fourier transform with respect to delay $\tau$ to get a 2D Fourier transform relation between the measured $I_\text{FROG}$ signal and the electric field $E(t)$. Since the measurement discards the signal's phase (because of the mag-suqare operation), the phase has to be retrieved using a suitable FROG algorithm and then you're done. Sorry for the long introduction but it's kind of a niche field and most people are not familiar with it - I'm coming to the point now.

One of the key properties of the FROG spectrogram, in particular for the second-harmonic FROG, is that its frequency marginal (integral with respect to the delay $\tau$) equals the autoconvolution of the original pulse's intensity spectrum, i.e.:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty I_\text{FROG}(\omega,\tau) \,d\tau  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty S(\omega')S(\omega'-\omega) \,d\omega'$$

where $S(\omega) = \left| \mathscr{F}\{E(t)\} \right|^2$ is the spectral intensity of the field $E(t)$ and $\mathscr{F}$ denotes Fourier transform. In the original publications about this technique and even in the book of the guy who invented it (R. Trebino) this marginal relationship was just asserted but never formally proven. I know it's correct because it's easy to simulate both sides of the equation with an arbitrary pulse $E(t)$, but I'm struggling with a solid mathematical proof, which was probably too trivial to include in all the publications about this technique. I would be grateful if anyone could enlighten me why it must be true.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems that if you apply the convolution theorem to the top equation, or in other words, write $I(\omega,\tau)=\left|((S)\text{convolution}(S')\right|^2$ but with S as E field in $\omega$ you will soon get that both are equivalent

Comment: I'm in the field and I dont care about this things :p

Comment: Thanks! I think it makes sense because the FT of the convolution cancels out with the FT in the FROG equation, right? So we get $I(\omega,\tau)=|\tilde{E}_0(\omega)*\tilde{E}_\tau(\omega)|^2$ where $\tilde{E}_0(\omega) = \mathscr{F}\{E(t)\}$ and $\tilde{E}_\tau(\omega) = \mathscr{F}\{E(t-\tau)\}$.

The FTs of both the E-field and the $\tau$-shifted E-field are of course related to $S(\omega)$ via a mod-square operation, but can you elaborate how an integral in $\tau$ makes it equal to a convolution of $S(\omega)$ with itself?